# Python GUI, on saving calculated output

Tags: python, user-interface

I am making an application that does some Electrical Calculations. We provide input, the calculations are all done within a class called  `EarthCalc(Frame)`,  and I have called that class as:

```
root = Tk()
C = EarthCalc(root)
```

Now, from that class I'm trying to save some the calculated outputs into a dictionary [defined outside class] so that I may be able to save the output in a notepad. But it is not working!

I have saved Input Data but the Output data is a blank:

```
def save_data():

    fileName = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',defaultextension=".txt",filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*.txt")])
    try:
        file = open(fileName, 'w')
        mydata = {"Conductor Material" : C.conductor_material.get(), "Soil Resistivity" : C.a.get(), "Earth Fault Current" : C.b.get(), "Fault Clearance Time" : C.c.get(), "Electrode Type" : "Pipe", "Electrode Length" : C.d.get(), "Diameter of Pipe" : C.e.get(), "Initial Temperature" : C.f.get(), "Conductor Strip Length" : C.g.get(), "Conductor Strip Width" : C.h.get(), "Conductor Strip Thickness" : C.i.get(), "Earth Grid Burial Depth" : C.j.get(), "Current Division Factor" : C.sf.get(), "Decrement Factor" : C.df.get(), "Surface Layer Resistivity" : C.slr.get(), "Surface Layer Thickness" : C.slt.get(), "Weight Category" : C.weight_category.get()}
        myop = {"Number of Pits" : C.pits}
        #myop = {"Number of Pits" : C.pits, "Protective Conductor Cross Section" : C.cross_section, "Earth Grid Resistance" : C.grid_resistance, "Maximum Grid Current" : C.maximum_grid_current, "Surface Layer Derating Factor" : C.sldf, "Touch Potential Criteria" : C.tpc, "Step Potential Criteria" : C.spc, "Ground Potential Rise" : C.gpr, "Grid Area" : C.area1}
        #textoutput = "Input Data \nConductor Material: %s \nSoil Resistivity: %s \nEarth Fault Time: %s \nFault Clearance Time: %s \nLength of Pipe: %s \nDiameter of Pipe: %s \nInitial Temperature: %s \nConductor Strip Length: %s \nConductor Strip Width: %s \nConductor Strip Thickness: %s \nGrid Burial Depth: %s \nCurrent Division Factor: %s \nDecrement Factor: %s \nSurface Layer Resistivity: %s \nSurface Layer Height: %s \nWeight Category: %s \n\n\nOutput Data " %self.conductor_material.get(), %self.a.get(), %self.b.grt(), %self.c.get(), %self.d.get(), %self.e.get(), %self.f.get(), %self.g.get(), %self.h.get(), %self.i.get(), %self.j.get(), %self.sf.get(), %self.df.get(), %self.slr.get(), %self.slt.get(), %self.weight_category.get()
        file.write("Input Data\n\n")
        for line in mydata:
            file.write(line + ": " + mydata[line] + "\n")
        file.write("\n\nOutput Data \n\n")
        file.write(myop["Number of Pits"])
        #for item in myop:
            #file.write(myop[item])
```

Help me resolve this. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few potential problems with your code. If you are using Python 2.x you should avoid the variable name "file" since it is also a pre-defined class, it will work in this short snippet, but might give you weird bugs in other cases. The name file is fine in Python3 though.

It is a bit problematic that you don't show what is in your except block since a crash (for example if Number of Pits is a number.write will return a TypeError) which in turn might lead to the program crashing before the data have actually been flushed to disk.

I would probably write it like this:

```
def save_data():
   fileName = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',defaultex»tension=".txt",filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*.txt")])

   try:
      with open(fileName,'w') as f:
         mydata = {"Conductor Material" :...
         myop = {"Number of Pits" : C.pits}
         f.write("Input Data\n\n")
         for line,value in mydata.iteritems():
            f.write("{0} : {1}\n".format(line, value ))
         f.write("\n\nOutput Data \n\n")
         f.write(str(myop["Number of Pits"]))
   except IOError as e:
      print "Error opening or writing {0}: {1}".format(fileName,e.message)
```